# Invalid Syntax 'jupiter notebook' while jupyter is installed +imported

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am currently learning code and having troubles with Jupyter in python.

I use Python3.10, I have upgraded pip,  modules are in the good PATH, and I have imported jupyter.

I tried to open the note book in two different ways in the interpreter:

```
#Input1
>>> jupyter notebook

#Output1
File "<stdin>", line 1
    jupyter notebook
            ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#Input2
>>> py -3.9 -m jupyter notebook
#Output2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -3.9 -m jupyter notebook
               ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also did it in the terminal in case... But I was getting som other error (translated from FR):

```
jupyter-notebook: The term "jupyter-notebook" is not recognized as a name
cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
To Line:1 character : 1
```

Do you have a clue of what's going on ?

Have a great day !

Comment: Have you tried "jupyter notebook" at the terminal?

Comment: Yes ! 

The 2nd block of code is the output when typing "jupyter notebook" !

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: the prefix `>>> ` looks like you're already in Python when trying to start a notebook server, this isn't how it's designed to work. you should be in your shell (i.e. cmd or power shell if you're in Windows).  just running your `py -3.9 -m jupyter notebook` command there should work

Comment: looks like you’re on windows. you should run `py  -m jupyter notebook` **in the terminal** (not the prompt.). If that doesn’t work, check that you’ve installed `jupyter-notebook` using `py -m pip install jupyter-notebook`

Answer (score 0):

MY jupyter notebook didn't work after installing and calling in CMD.

then i only use "pip install simplejson" in command prompt (cmd) . Then i write "jupyter notebook" and it work!

someone uses "pip uninstall simplejson" before "pip install simplejson".

Comment: how does this help solve the original question?

Comment: Just did what you suggested but I still got the 'Invalid syntax' error message...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

looks like you’re on windows.

You should run `py  -m jupyter notebook` **in the terminal** (not the python prompt.).

If that doesn’t work, check that you’ve installed `jupyter-notebook` using `py -m pip install notebook`.

Also, if you’re using `python 3.10`, you should *not* run `py -3.9`

Comment: Just trie install jupyter notebook with your code and get this:
`PS C:\Users\Leo\Documents\VSCode> py -m pip install jupyter-notebook
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-notebook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter-notebook`

Comment: oh yeah sorry, it’s just `py -m pip install notebook`

Comment: Installation worked perfectly, however, I still got the same msg...
`jupyter-notebook: The term "jupyter-notebook" is not recognized as a name
cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
To Line:1 character : 1`